# How can I get the files modified in a directory in a particular period of time using c++?

Tags: visual-c++

Hi 
In a sample App I develop, I would like to retrieve the details of files modified in a particular time period.

Or simply... I have a time with me (say june 6th 2011 10:00 AM) and would like to get the list of files in a directory(say C:\MyFolder) which is modified after that partiicular time.

I have tried a method..

```
   CFileFind finder;
   szFile = _T("C:\\MyFolder\\*.*");
BOOL bFound = finder.FindFile( szFile );
CTime fileTime;
CTime fileCreateTime;
while ( bFound )
{
          bFound = finder.FindNextFile();
    finder.GetLastWriteTime(fileTime);
    finder.GetCreationTime(fileCreateTime);
    szFile = finder.GetFilePath();
    if((startTime < fileTime) || (startTime < fileCreateTime))
            {

                 ......
```

Is there any other windows apis available for this or is there any better method than this..?

any one please reply...

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the exact APIs, but I'd start here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363798(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply..
I have checked The msdn about Change Journal..
But 1 doubt.. Is it Possible to get the details of the files modified before the last shutdown from change Journal?

In other words will Journal keeps the details of the files modfied at any time or only those modified after the current system startup?