# How to get the time of file Renamed

Tags: visual-c++

Last time I have asked a question regarding the retrieval of list of files modified after a particular time

[How can I get the files modified in a directory in a particular period of time using c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248474/how-can-i-get-the-files-modified-in-a-directory-in-a-particular-period-of-time-us)

and I tried the following code

```
CFileFind finder;
szFile = _T("C:\\MyFolder\\*.*");
BOOL bFound = finder.FindFile( szFile );
CTime fileTime;
CTime fileCreateTime;
while ( bFound )
{
bFound = finder.FindNextFile();
    finder.GetLastWriteTime(fileTime);
    finder.GetCreationTime(fileCreateTime);
    szFile = finder.GetFilePath();
    if((startTime < fileTime) || (startTime < fileCreateTime))
        {
           ............
```

the details of the modified files can be retrieved with the above code..
but I cant get the details of renamed files.

If i rename a file in that folder, its create and modified time is same as the old file.
only the accessed time is getting changed.

but the accesstime is changed even when the file is opened and not modified.

So by retrieving accesstime i didnt get the relevent details..

any one please help, how can i identify the renamed files too....

Answer (score 1):

From the [File times](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) MSDN article:

> The system records file times when applications create, access, and write to files.

Renames time is not recorded. You can't get that information. You might get some indication of whether a file was renamed by looking at the directory time information, but that won't tell you which one was renamed.

If you explained your goal with more detail, maybe someone can find an alternative solution, but as is, what you're asking doesn't sound possible.

Comment: Hi..Thanks For the reply...
My intention is to get the list of files modified, renamed, or created in a folder after a particular time...

Comment: Is there any method to find the actions made on a file?
i mean the last action was write, rename, move etc...
if so I think I can get it by checking the last action of the files having new access time